# How to find complexity of a recursion where the step is defined in terms of a cube root?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

T(1) = 1

T(n) = T(n^1/3) + 1

How can I solve it? By "solve" I mean to found it's "complexity" (I don't really know how to say it in English), such as O(nlogn) ecc.

I couldn't guess the substitution method; i go nowhere with the iteration method, and I can't apply Master Theorem.

I'm arrived here, but I'm not sure:

T(n) = T(n^(1/3^k))) +k

Can you give me and advice please?

Comment: That doesn't look recursive to me, `T(n)` is not written in terms of `T(n-1)`.  What am I missing ?

Comment: @Ilya Ivanov By `solve` he means finding the algorithmic order of the recursion.

Comment: @IlyaIvanov I edited it for a better explaination

Comment: Is there another break criteria? If `n` is not initialized with 1 then `n` can never reach 1.

Comment: To members voting to close as an off-topic: this is an on-topic question; perhaps you'd get a solution at the math forum faster, but it does not make the question an off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Nico hit the nail on the head. If `n` > 1 then we can never reach `T(1)`. I guess that means the complexity is undefined for `n > 1`?

Comment: I think this is very on-topic for SO. However, if it has to go to a different forum, I would think the comp sci se (http://cs.stackexchange.com/) would be better than the math one.

Comment: BTW the stable value for n is about 2.32 (http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=n%20%3D%20n%5E%281%2F3%29%20%2B%201)

Comment: @G.Bach I found that problem like this, inside an Universitary set of exercises, without other explainations or conditions

Comment: Assuming that exist `k0` such as `n - k0 = n^1/3` then you could express `T(n)` as `T(n) = T(n - k0) + 1` then `T(n - k0) = T((n - k0)^1/3) + 1`, again, assuming that exists `k1` such as `n - k0 - k1 = (n - k0)^1/3` then `T(n - k0) = T(n - k0 - k1) + 1`... Don't know what to do next... XD

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark: Recursions don't have to be written in terms of n-1. See for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3607161/towers-of-hanoi-with-k-pegs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll try to formulate some possible solutions. You can pick one depending on further constraints.

The recursion will run until `n` becomes `1`. This is:

```
1 = n^(1/3^k)
```

or more generally

```
b = n^(1/3^k)
```

where `k` is the recursion depth. Solving this for `k` yields:

```
ln(b) = 1/3^k * ln(n)
ln(ln(b) / ln(n)) = k * ln(1/3)
-ln(ln(b) / ln(n)) / ln(3) = k
```

If we set `b` to 1, then the equation becomes unsolvable, because `ln(0)` is not specified. This would be equivalent to an endless recursion.

However, we can say that in the last recursion `n` should be "roughly 1". So we actually have a `b != 1`. Then k is:

```
k = -ln(ln(b) / ln(n)) / ln(3)
  = -ln(c1 / ln(n)) / c2
  = -(ln(c1) - lnln(n)) / c2
  = (-c3 + lnln(n)) / c2
```

This should be `O(log log n)`.

If you want to truncate `n` to its integer part, the calculation becomes pretty messy, because you have special cases after each step. However, we could approximate the result by specifying `b = 1.999999`. This would yield the same complexity as above.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a recursive function, so what i did understand is that 
T(n)= T(integerpart(cubicsquare(n)) +1 ;

in this case :

```
S=0;
if (n>=1){
S++;
N= n;
while  (N>1){
N=integerpart(N^1/3);
S++;
}

}
T(n)= S ;
```

that's mean that T(n) is a simple function : with integer bound, and the width of the  keme interval is 2^(3^k) - 2^(3^(k-1))

you can see, first interval is  if n in ]1,8[  T(n)=2; then if n in [8,252[ ,T(n)=3... 
so, as we can say then  that  t(2^(3^k)) = k+1 ;
then t(n) ~O(ln(ln(n))/ln(3)) (consider suite 2^3^k)