# Reve's puzzle recursive solution

Tags: algorithm, haskell, recursion, functional-programming

The classic [tower of hanoi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi) problem has quite elegant solution in haskell:

```
type Peg = String
type Move = (Peg, Peg)
hanoi :: Integer -> Peg -> Peg -> Peg -> [Move]
hanoi 0 _ _ _ = []
hanoi n from to via = (hanoi (n - 1) from via to) ++ [(from, to)] ++ (hanoi (n - 1) via to from)
```

I'm struggling to find a solution for the same problem with four pegs (also known as Reve's puzzle) in as few moves as possible.

It's widely known that minimal amount of steps for three pegs is 2^n-1. For 15 disks it's 32676, while for four pegs it's only 129 as mentioned in [cis194 homework#1 ex. 6](https://www.seas.upenn.edu/~cis194/spring13/hw/01-intro.pdf). Here is my take on the task:

```
hanoiiii :: Integer -> Peg -> Peg -> Peg -> Peg -> [Move]
hanoiiii n from to via1 via2
  | n == 0 = []
  | n == 1 = [(from, to)]
  | n == 3 = [(from, via1), (from, via2), (from, to), (via2, to), (via1, to)]
  | otherwise = (hanoiiii (n - 1) from via1 to via2) ++ [(from, to)] ++ (hanoiiii (n - 1) via1 to from via2)
```

> length $ hanoiiii 15 "a" "b" "c" "d"
>
> 24575

As you can see it's suboptimal, if even working. Please help me to find proper solution.

Comment: Related: There is a C++ implementation of the 4 pegs version and a Haskell implementation of the even more general `k` pegs version in my question and its answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3607161/towers-of-hanoi-with-k-pegs Note that this is an open problem, and it is not known if an efficient algorithm will produce an optimal solution.