# Modified Towers of Hanoi with 5 pegs n disks

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, graph

My Question is that I have a Tower of Hanoi with 5 pegs but movement is limited to

> Start -> Aux1 <-> Aux2 <-> Aux3 -> Destination

1. Start can only move out
2. Only Aux1, Aux2, Aux3 can exchange disks
3. Once a disk arrive Destination, it cannot go back

How can I expand the algorithm from 3 peg to 5 peg version with n disks?

> n = 1:

- Aux1 -> Aux2
- Aux2 -> Aux3

> n >= 2 :

- Hanoi(Aux1,Aux2,Aux3,n-1)
- Aux1 -> Aux2
- Hanoi(Aux3,Aux2,Aux1,n-1)
- Aux2 -> Aux3
- Hanoi(Aux1,Aux2,Aux3,n-1)

Comment: This video and its previous part may come in useful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bdMfjfT0lKk

Comment: There's a very good explanation of the process in the accepted answer to [Towers of Hanoi with K pegs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3607161/62576); the only reason I'm not voting to close this as a duplicate is that yours is tagged C++ and the other is Haskell/F#.

Comment: @3131 So I will need to count using 0,1,2,3,4 with Sierpinski triangle right?

Comment: here possibly a class mate Q duplicate [tower of hanoi - How to not skip over a peg every recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48727627/2521214)

Comment: Well, moderator deleted my answer and says to vote for close, but you cannot do that if the answer wasn't accepted or upvoted. See answer using Spektre's link.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the answer is 14^-3 because the inverse function overcomes the derivative throughout the newton 5th law

Comment: Your answer is unrelated to the question (what is 'the fifth law of Newton?').